# Check if $\sum \frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to know if the series $\sum \frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$ converges. First I need to know if $\frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$ converges to $0$, because if it doesnt, the series doesn't converge either. I tried to simplify to $\frac{n!}{k^n}$ but this brings me nowhere.

I also tried with Cauchy but I should only go on with Cauchy knowing if  $\frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$ converges to $0$. And anyways applying Cauchy I get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{k}$ which I do not know how to keep operating. 
I guess assuming that $k$ is any number so the lim is infinite which brings nowhere again.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you formulated your question using this- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference !

Comment: It is better to use d'Alambert test (quotient test).

Comment: So we agree that the sum is on $k$ ? $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$

Comment: I think that the sum is on $n$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: What is the range of $k$? $\mathbb{R}^+$ or $\mathbb{N}^+$?

Answer (score 2):

$a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$, 
$a_{n+1}=\frac{((n+1)!)^2}{(k(n+1))!}$, 
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(kn+1)(kn+2)\ldots (kn+k)}$

Then if $k>2$ the convergence follows from $a_{n+1}/a_n \to 0$

if $k=2$ the convergence follows from $a_{n+1}/a_n \to 1/4$

If $k=1$ the series is divergent.